# Fzaninotto/Faker IF statement when generating fake data

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, faker

I am currently trying to fake seed quite a vast table of mine. I am currently using Laravel 4.1.

I have one column which is set to NULL, because it only has to be filled if the previous column is set to '1', for example.

I currently have:

```
$alerts = 
[[
    'user_id' => $i,
    'reference' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 1),
    'type' => rand(1,2),
    'category' => rand(1,4),
    'headline' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 2),
    'description' => $faker->realText(150)               
]];
```

So, should **'type'** be '1', I want the following two fields 'range_to' and 'range_from' to be then faked.

Is this possible logically? Any pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your carry using if statement

```
$alerts = 
[[
    'user_id' => $i,
    'reference' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 1),
    'type' => rand(1,2),
    'category' => rand(1,4),
    'headline' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 2),
    'description' => $faker->realText(150)               
]];

foreach($alerts as $key=>$alert){
    if( $alert['type'] != 1 ){
        $alerts[$key]['category'] = $alerts[$key]['headline'] = $alerts[$key]['description'] = NULL ;
    }
}
```

So you set your alerts as you want, then you loop on them and apply the condition you want if it exist then you edit the array.

in above example it will loop `$alerts` and for each array if ['type'] not equal 1 it will set category,headline and description of that array to NULL..

Comment: Zalaboza, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I can see the logic, but I can't see from your example how to implement it. Is it possible to use my full example above to show me, please?